# How to use a list array menu in android app development

Tags: java, android, xml

I quite new to android app dev, and I am trying to use a list array to create a menu, I have done this but only the first item will work. This is the code I have used to create the menu:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

String menuItems[] = { "MainActivity","BMI Key", "BMI Chart", "BMI Calculator"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menuItems));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String menu = menuItems[position];
    try {
    Class classCR = Class.forName("rolston.c.bmi.calculator." + menu);
    Intent crIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, classCR);
    startActivity(crIntent);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException a){
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

}

My main question is how to get "BMI Key" etc to open up a specific xml file?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had to name the string correctly in the array, then add the corresponding java file to the android manifest.

Not as difficult as I thought.

Thanks